# Performance of multiple awaits compared to Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous

### General Information

I want to improve the performance of a program issuing multiple HTTP requests to the same external API endpoint. Therefore, I have created a console application to perform some tests. The method `GetPostAsync` sends an asynchronous HTTP request to the external API and returns the result as a string.

```
private static async Task<string> GetPostAsync(int id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{id}");
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Additionally, I have implemented the methods below to compare the execution time of multiple calls to `await` and `Task.WhenAll`.

```
private static async Task TaskWhenAll(IEnumerable<int> postIds)
{   
    var tasks = postIds.Select(GetPostAsync);
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task MultipleAwait(IEnumerable<int> postIds)
{
    foreach (var postId in postIds)
    {
        await GetPostAsync(postId);
    }
}
```

---

### Test Results

Using the integrated `Stopwatch` class, I have measured the timings of the two methods and interestingly enough, the approach using `Task.WhenAll` performed way better than its counterpart:

> ***Issue 50 HTTP requests***
>
> 1. TaskWhenAll: ~650ms
> 2. MultipleAwait: ~4500ms

Why is the method using `Task.WhenAll` so much faster and are there any negative effects (i.e exception handling) when choosing this approach over the other?

Comment: Because with the `foreach`, you're firing requests one at a time. That means each request has to wait for the previous to finish before it can start. The `WhenAll` pattern fires all the requests at once instead of one after another. No waiting involved. A potential negative is that some APIs might have limits, and by firing 50 requests at once, you might hit those limits. But that depends on the external API, not the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is the method using `Task.WhenAll` so much faster

It is faster because you are not awaiting `GetPostAsync`. So actually every time you `await client.GetAsync($"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{id}");` the control will be returned to the caller which then can make another HTTP request. If you consider that HTTP request is much longer than creating the new client you effectively have the parallelism by running multiple HTTP requests in parallel. The `WhenAll` will just create a suspension point and wait for all tasks to finish.

With the multiple await approach, you make HTTP requests sequentially one by one by `await GetPostAsync(postId)` from `foreach` loop. You start the task but at the same time, you make a suspension point and wait for it to finish.

> are there any negative effects (i.e exception handling, etc.) when
>   choosing this approach over the other?

There are no negative effects, using `await/async` pattern handling exception become just, as usual, using `try-catch` block. `WhenAll` will aggregate all exception from each task which is in `Faulted` state.

Comment: `WhenAll` has nothing to do with it.  His second method with the `foreach` is running the tasks **one at a time**.  The tasks are already running _before_ he gets to the `WhenAll`

Comment: @MickyD I didn't say that `WhenAll` starts tasks. I thought more about approach 1 and approach 2... I will clarify.

Comment: @MickyD What point are you trying to make with your comment? Johnny's answer explicitly states that parallelism is the reason that method 1 is faster. This answer never implied that the `WhenAll` is the reason method 1 was faster.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Awaiting hot tasks with `WhenAll` is equivalent with awaiting them individually in a loop. There is some overhead but it is minimal. Also there is a difference in the error handling. `await WhenAll` throws only one error. This is the by design behavior of
`await`. On the other hand individual awaits in a loop are catching all errors.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think you are wrong about awaiting because there is a difference between awaiting all and awaiting one by one. About the error, yes only one Aggregate Exception as I answered.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, unfortunately (or fortunately) they aren't equivalents. Awaiting in the loop is equal to sequence of awaits when each next task is fired in continuation of previous (the same happens in the loop). It's not the same as to request all task at once. There is of course synchronous part which will be executed sequentially, but starting from the an asynchronous point they run concurrently.

Comment: @PatrickTucci I think the point I am making is pretty obvious.  Grammar

Comment: @Dmytro Mukalov I am talking about **hot** tasks, in other words for tasks that have already started. In that case it doesn't matter if you await them individually or all at once. I am **not** talking about the code provided by the OP, because his code does not create all the tasks at once. They are created one after the other and awaited in the same loop. In this case the tasks are running sequentially indeed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, For already started tasks yes, but that isn't the case for code provided by OP. `WhenAll` **does** start tasks in particular cases (when they provided as non-materialized `IEnumerable<Task>`) by doing the collection materialization and that's what is actually happening inside OP `TaskWhenAll` method.

Comment: @MickyD In this specific case the tasks are started exactly by `WhenAll`.

Comment: @Johnny the `await` throws the unwrapped exception of the first faulted task in the list (not the first chronologically). Generally this exception is not an `AggregateException`, althought it can be if the exception of the faulted task has a **nested** `AggregateException`. This behavior is by design, to alleviate the programmers from having to deal with an AggregateException after every tiny await.

Comment: @Dmytro Mukalov we agree then. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias please read, remarks  chapter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Johnny this is the documentation of `Task.WhenAll`, but the `await` makes things different. When the `await` throws you have only the exception in the `catch()`. You don't have the task returned from `WhenAll`, to query its `Exception` property, because the code that would return this task has failed. Please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article. The interesting part starts at the next paragraph after Figure 4.

Comment: If you wrap await in try catch you could catch aggregate exception with inner exceptions from all faulted tasks.